# How to share ASP.NET web pages using dynamic IDs to Facebook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I am intermediate ASP.NET developer and I am trying to solve a problem regarding ASP.NET, C#, and a Microsoft Access database. If anyone has a solution for this question, please help me out.

My ASP.NET website has multiple pages of information, and those pages have new IDs like `/information.aspx?id=1`, `/information.aspx?id=2`, `/information.aspx?id=3`, … and so on.

Now, how do I share a particular page (like `/information.aspx?id=3`) with image and content previews? Currently, when I share the URL with `id`s on Facebook, the posts always display a logo with the content, but I want the preview image to be set dynamically based on images already available in the content.

I have also used Open Graph tags such as:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://website.com/information.aspx?id=1" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://website.com/logobg.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<%# Eval("image1") %>" />
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide an explanation of what's not working? Facebook is fine accepting URLs that contain (and depend upon) query string parameters. And, obviously, there shouldn't be an issue dynamically data binding values to your Open Graph metadata tags. What issue are you running into?

Comment: Importantly, I'd try to separate out the ASP.NET question from the Facebook question. When you view the source of your web page, are you seeing the `<% Eval("image1") %>` bound correctly, and outputting the expected image? Also, is there a reason you're keeping the `logobg.png` in place, since it sounds like you'd prefer the second image?

Comment: Hello sir, when I post asp.net website url using Id (www.website.com/information.aspx?id=1) that time I have problem in display image only. how can I display that particular page image too on the facebook post.

Comment: I have already used facebook share api and In that I have done code like this :<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="<%# string.Format("www.website.com/informations.aspx?aid={0}", Eval("aid")) %>" data-title="<%# Eval("title") %>" data-media="<%# Eval("image1") %>"></div> this code work fine but why that image not display which connected with database.